# Geospatial Conda Environment Setup in Python

Tags: python, installation, conda, geopandas, pyproj

I just started a new job and I have to set up my geospatial environment in Windows (I was a mac user before). I am having trouble navigating around geopandas bug [#830](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/830). Based on the comments for the bug, it looks like if I can downgrade pyproj to version 1.9.4 it will fix the issue. BUT, I cannot get 1.9.4 installed for one reason or another. I have tried the following without success:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyproj==1.9.4
```

When I try this, it gets hung up in the "Solving Environment" stage.

I then tried this:

```
pip install pyproj==1.9.4
```

but, I get this error:

```
Collecting pyproj-1.9.4
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyproj-1.9.4 (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyproj-1.9.4
```

So, I tried downloading the tar file and doing the following:

```
pip install "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\pyproj-1.9.4.tar"
```

but got this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such 
file or directory: 'C:\Users\myname\Downloads\pyproj-1.9.4.tar'
```

I have actually done more than this (it has been a long 8 hours), but I am hoping that somebody smarter than I can put me out of my misery :-) I am using conda version  4.5.11 and python 3.5.6.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try the "solution" mentioned in https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/830#issuecomment-426116505

Comment: `Solving Environment` can sometimes take **aaaaages.** How long did you actually give it?

Comment: Also, are you trying to set up a new environment for this or are you trying to downgrade a package in an existing env? I would definitely try a new environment and specify the packages you want in the `conda create` command.

Comment: @nekomatic All in all, I spent near 15 hours, but I think I finally got it to work. As joris suggested, one of the temporary fixes over at GitHub worked. Thanks for your help!